# Sorting a 2D float arrray by value of 2nd dimension

Tags: java

```
 Arrays.sort(copied, new Comparator<float[]>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(float[] o1, float[] o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return o2[7].compareTo(o1[7]);
    }
});
```

the copied array is use looks like this

`[10.0, 34.34, 34.42, 34.1, 34.35, 5244700.0, 34.35, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0][10.0, 34.34, 34.42, 34.1, 34.35, 5244700.0, 34.35, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0 ].......`

but somehow the compiler errors the return line :

```
Cannot invoke compareTo(float) on the primitive type float
```

pls help

Comment: I think you need to explicitly cast the value as a float object - can anyone confirm this?

Comment: You can't call compareTo on a float as they're primitive data types. Try to either use normal comparisons (<>!= etc) or use Float's (as in the wrapper class') compareTo method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return Float.compare(o2[7],o1[7]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use the [Float](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html) class and not the float primitive

Answer (score 0):

You are using a primitive, which you are trying to dereference by trying to invoke a method on it. Noting that primitives are not classes and thus don't have methods. Hence the error cannot `invoke`.

Change your method signature to

```
public int compare(Float[] o1, Float[] o2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return o2[7].compareTo(o1[7]);
}
```

which will give you access to the `.compare` function

Remember to pass `Float[]`. apparently Java does not autobox arrays